# LD_PRELOAD and thread local variable

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, pthreads

I have a shared library (libtest.cpp) and a simple program (test.cpp). I want them to share a thread local variable **gVar**. The shared library is linked through LD_PRELOAD.

Here is my code for the shared library libtest.cpp:

```cpp
#include<stdio.h>

__thread int gVar;

void print_gVar(){
  printf("%d\n", gVar);
}
```

Below is the code for test.cpp.

```cpp
#include<stdio.h>

__thread int gVar;

void __attribute__((weak)) print_gVar();

int main(){
  gVar = 10;
  print_gVar(); 
  return 0;
}
```

And I use the following script to compile and run them.

```
g++ -g -shared -fPIC -olibtest.so libtest.cpp
g++ -g -fPIC -o test test.cpp
LD_PRELOAD=./libtest.so ./test
```

The expected result is 10 because the assignment in test.cpp will affect the gVar in libtest.cpp. However, I only got 0. It seems that the the gVar in libtest.cpp and the gVar in test.cpp are not linked.

I did some additional tests:

If I add `__attribute__((weak))` to the declaration of `gVar` in any of the files, the output is still 0.

If I remove `__thread` from both files, then the result is 10 (successful).

If I add `extern` and `__attribute__((weak))` to the declaration of `gVar` in libtest.cpp, there will be segmentation fault.

I guess there must be something wrong with `LD_PRELOAD` and `__thread`. But I cannot figure out.

Could anyone tell me how I can make it work? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not possible, since thread-local-storage requires per-thread initialisation.

`LD_PRELOAD` will load the library even before the standard library is loaded, which messes up TLS initialisation.

**Update:**

Please read sections 2 and 3 of [ELF Handling For Thread-Local Storage](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/tls.pdf)

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you please give me some more references?

Comment: You're welcome, just added it. Sadly, nothing specific to this problem is mentioned but you should get a good idea of how TLS initialisation works in the first place.

Comment: @voodooattack I don't quite understand your answer. Can you elaborate it a little bit why it does not work? Plus, do you imply that LD_PRELOADed library cannot use tls? This sounds incorrect to me. Many scenarios need to use LD_PRELOADed library along with tls, right? E.g., https://github.com/jemalloc/jemalloc/issues/937